# Automated, script and template based video editing

Tags: editing, automation

Basic idea - I have a lot of .mp3's that I want to turn into video which would contain static background image and audio visualizer. While it's easy to do this by hand, It would take a lot of time (lots and lots of mp3s). So I was thinking of perhaps somehow automating all of this, but all I found was pretty much moviePY or another solution is AHK script for any video editing software.

Isn't there any better solutions? Most of the stuff would remain the same, So pretty much in theory I'd just need a template with static background image and audio visualizer effect and I'd just change audio track.

Comment: You could do this with ffmpeg if the aesthetics of its waveform visualizer is acceptable to you.

Answer (score 1):

Automation Software might be a good option, although you'd need to give yourself a day or more to just get yourself up to speed learning curve wise.

AutoIt is free, and you can basically code your scripts and then compile it into a program or batch file which you could run on a folder of files.

I use a program called WinAutomation, which is similar to AutoIt, but you have to purchase ($800ish). But it makes task automation, even to a very high level of sophistication, and allows you to automate human processes.

With WinAutomation you could create a program that basically opens sequentially each file, loads it into your editor, adds video to a timeline, random, or based on variables, applies filters, sets up settings, exports, when finished, it would do the next one.

But again, learning curve wise.

Either way, its going to come down to coding/programming/scripting. I don't code enough to be proficient at it, so while I can cut/paste/modify and even write basic code in a few programming languages, a package like WinAutomation allows me to make programs that work like actual programs, and do very complex tasks, which script/code wise would require a lot of time to learn language wise.

Look at AutoIt. Its used to make so many apps and programs, and again, its free, with tons of resources and projects you can download to get a feel for how it's build architecture works.

Answer (score 0):

I use ffmpeg to combine a static PNG with MP3 to create a composite MP4. The Job Listings video on https://joblist4u.com is created daily using ffmpeg to render the finished MP4. The process is 100% unattended. The AutiIT and WnAutomation are scripting shells, and Windows Powershell is more suitable and is part of Windows 10.